# How to specify max param in Struts2's Date Field Validator?

Tags: java, struts2, validation, struts-validation, dateinterval

This is my validation field of date type and `current` is an hidden variable having get & setter in action class:

```xml
<param name="min">01/01/1920</param>
<param name="max">${new java.util.Date(current}</param>  
<message>Your Birth date must be less than ${min} and ${max} date!</message>
```

Please help the above code is working for min but the max value is blank..

Answer (score 0):

Action:

```java
private Date current;

public Date getCurrent(){
    return current;
}
```

Validator:

```xml
<field name="birthday">
    <field-validator type="date">
        <param name="minExpression">01/01/1920</param> 
        <param name="maxExpression">${current}</param> <!--calls getCurrent();-->
        <message>
            <![CDATA[ Your Birth date must be between ${min} and ${max}! ]]>
        </message>             
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Also take a look [at the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/date-validator.html), it's all explained there.